# Failing to install grub and conifgure target system bootloader with UEFI on Ubuntu Server on Dell inspiron 3252

Tags: boot, server, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I've been trying to install Ubuntu server 22,04.2 on an old desktop that I have. I've been able to install the OS when in legacy mode, with no encryption. However, I want to boot the system in UEFI mode, with secure boot enabled, and the drive encrypted. The desktop is a Dell Inspiron 3252 with the most up to date bios on dell's website.

I've attempted to install it using a USB with Ventoy installed and a separate bootable USB made using Linux Mint's built in bootable USB maker. I've also used the built in verification tool to verify the iso file.

The installation process ends with the following errors with both USB sticks:

efibootmgr: entry 1009 does not exist
Fail: Installing grub to target device
Fail: configuring target system bootloader

[The output surrounding the errors can be seen with this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRmHb.png)

Based on another post on this site, I thought that there may not be enough room in the systems EFI flash. I've tried running the installer with the no_efi_storage_paranoia, but it doesn't seem to change anything. However, I may be formatting it incorrectly:

Linux    caspar/file_name    --no_efi_storage_paranoia

I would really appreciate any help as I am at my wits end.

Comment: I do not think this runs in the server version as it needs gui. Do you have live Desktop or download the somewhat older ISO (over more updated ppa). Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Sorry this took so long, busy week. here is the link to the pastebin. http://sprunge.us/NI3Nxy . Thank you for your help. I did seem to recommend repairing the efi partition.

Comment: This is an Ubuntu question & answer site. Mint is off-topic as we do not know what changes Mint has done, as it is not an official flavor of Ubuntu. But did you orginally install with UEFI Secure boot on? Update may have turned it on and you do not have the Secure Boot/signed versions of grub & kernel. Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site.

Comment: Sorry, I just had a USB with Mint on it lying around and I figured it would work since it is based on Ubuntu. So, did you notice in the paste bin that is says my kernel or grub are not signed? I don't see that.

Comment: That Boot-Repair wanted to purge & totally reinstall the signed version to me indicates that Secure Boot is on. Report also says it is on under the UEFI settings.

Comment: I downloaded the iso for the server version directly from Ubuntu's website. Does Ubuntu not ship ISO compatible with secure boot? Sorry, I don't know a lot about secure boot. I would just like to have it on, so I can encrypt my boot drive for this server.

Comment: How you boot install media, is then how it installs. If UEFI Secure Boot is on when you boot live installer &  if that is default boot mode, then install will be with Secure Boot. If Secure boot off, then that is how it installs. But then if you turn on Secure Boot, or an update resets to defaults then you may not be able to boot. You just need to always be consistent in settings & how you boot.